# Ubuntu18.04 boot freeze after downgrade kernel to 5.3.0-62-generic to cope with nvidia driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel

As Nvidia driver can not work properly with kernel 5.4, I have to downgrade my hwe kernel on Ubuntu 18.04 to kernel 5.3 by editing the file /etc/default/grub and do upgrade-grub. However, after I reboot with kernel 5.3, the system freeze at the DELL logo screen (I am using a Dell workstation with dual system, windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04).

Does anyone know how to deal with this kind of problem? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if your system freezes at the DELL logo, that is presumably before the bootloader (grub) even gets to load your kernel, i.e. you might have misconfigured your grub.

Comment: Hi, thanks a bunch for your prompt response! Actually I have just followed this instruction here [link](http://www.humans-enabled.com/2014/08/how-to-set-default-grub-kernel-boot.html), comment out `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in `/etc/default/grub ` and add a new line `GRUB_DEFAULT='gnulinux-advanced-6ab014ae-b403-4d05-8444-b8061fa6b31b>gnulinux-5.3.0-62-generic-advanced-6ab014ae-b403-4d05-8444-b8061fa6b31b'` based on what I got using `grep gnulinux /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, after that I `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I have restored the `/etc/default/grub` back to original with `GRUB_DEFAULT=0`, and restored my nvidia drive to `nouveau`. This time I can boot with `5.3.0-62-generic` listed by `Advanced options for Ubuntu`. However, after I reinstall Nvidia driver 435, the system refuse to boot with `5.3.0-62-generic` again. Really have no idea what can I do to fix the Nvidia driver vs kernel version issue...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I installed nvidia-driver-440 instead of 435, and the Nvidia driver vs kernel version issue can be finally settled without the need to downgrade the kernel version.